# Parsing REST API Response

Tags: json, parsing, go

I am new to golang. I was writing a program to parse the json response of the API: https://httpbin.org/get. I have used the following code to parse the response:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

type Headers struct {
    Close  string `json:"Connection"`
    Accept string `json:"Accept"`
}

type apiResponse struct {
    Header Headers `json:"headers"`
    URL    string  `json:"url"`
}

func main() {
    apiRoot := "https://httpbin.org/get"
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", apiRoot, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Couldn't prepare request")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    response, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()
    var responseStruct apiResponse
    err = json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&responseStruct)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", responseStruct)
}
```

When I run this code the output is:

```
$ go run parse.go
{{close } https://httpbin.org/get}
```

From the output, as we can see the "Accept" key in json response is not decoded. Why is it so? How can I parse that string from response body?

Comment: Headers are not part of the Body. They are already "pre-read" and parsed into `http.Repsonse.Header`.

Comment: @mkopriva: It is not headers, the content shown here is from the body of the response. You can test it via postman

Comment: @Arun the response is a reflection of the request headers you sent the URL. Your browser sends different headers than the Go http client.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer: I have understood the situation. I have set the headers same as the browser, and I got the results.

Comment: @Arun my bad, I misread your question.

Comment: @Arun you clearly missed something. I set the Accept header and got back a valid response. Use some sniffer to see what's really going on.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is doing well but here I think your `Accept` key does not return from API  that's why it's not showing the `Accept` value. To check the `key`, `value` pair of your struct, use the below `print` method.

```
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", responseStruct)
```

To overcome from this situation you need to send `Accept` with request into `header` before request the [API](https://httpbin.org/get) like:

```
req.Header.Set("Accept", "value")
response, err := hc.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

Then you will get the `Accept` value in `decoded` struct as :

```
{Header:{Accept:value Close:close} URL:https://httpbin.org/get}
```

Comment: Running the code locally, the response doen't contain the Accept value.

Comment: @saddam: I have printed that but it does not contain Accept. It shows `{Header:{Accept: Close:close} URL:https://httpbin.org/get}`

Comment: @Arun the response you got from httpbin doesn't contain Accept because you did not send an Accept header. Send one and you'll get one back.

Answer (score 0):

apiResponse is unexported - you need to change it to something like APIResponse. You may find that pasting the JSON you want to decode into https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ will make all the code you need!

```golang
type AutoGenerated struct {
    Args struct {
    } `json:"args"`
    Headers struct {
        Accept                  string `json:"Accept"`
        AcceptEncoding          string `json:"Accept-Encoding"`
        AcceptLanguage          string `json:"Accept-Language"`
        Connection              string `json:"Connection"`
        Dnt                     string `json:"Dnt"`
        Host                    string `json:"Host"`
        UpgradeInsecureRequests string `json:"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests"`
        UserAgent               string `json:"User-Agent"`
    } `json:"headers"`
    Origin string `json:"origin"`
    URL    string `json:"url"`
}
```

Comment: I think the apiResponse unexported is not a problem because I am calling it from the same file. Thanks for providing link to `json-to-go` tool.

Comment: Correct - it is the members that need to be exported for the JSON package to pick them up. https://play.golang.org/p/P2QRiaE6Gfg shows your code works fine as long as the API returns the headers you expect.